# generate 3d coordinates of given address using java google map api

Tags: java, maps

I have a code of geocoding an address in Java that generates latitude and longitude of a given address but in my project i want the way to generate 3D coordinates of an address like (x1,x2,x3) and (y1,y2,y3) form. How do I get this?

```
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;`
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLEncoder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Node;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
    import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
    public class GeocodingSample {

    // URL prefix to the geocoder
    private static final String GEOCODER_REQUEST_PREFIX_FOR_XML =      

    "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml";

    public static final void main (String[] argv) throws IOException, 

    XPathExpressionException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {

    // query address
    String address = "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA";

    // prepare a URL to the geocoder
    URL url = new URL(GEOCODER_REQUEST_PREFIX_FOR_XML + "?address=" +

    URLEncoder.encode(address, "UTF-8") + "&sensor=false");

    // prepare an HTTP connection to the geocoder
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    Document geocoderResultDocument = null;
    try {
    // open the connection and get results as InputSource.
    conn.connect();
    InputSource geocoderResultInputSource = new 

   InputSource(conn.getInputStream());

   // read result and parse into XML Document
   geocoderResultDocument =  



   DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
   .parse(geocoderResultInputSource);
   } finally {
   conn.disconnect();
   }

   // prepare XPath
   XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

   // extract the result
   NodeList resultNodeList = null;

   // a) obtain the formatted_address field for every result
   resultNodeList = (NodeList)   

   xpath.evaluate("/GeocodeResponse/result/formatted_address", 

   geocoderResultDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
   for(int i=0; i<resultNodeList.getLength(); ++i) {
   System.out.println(resultNodeList.item(i).getTextContent());
   }

   // b) extract the locality for the first result
   resultNodeList = (NodeList)  

   xpath.evaluate("/GeocodeResponse/result[1]/
   address_component[type/text()='locality']/long_name",   

   geocoderResultDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
   for(int i=0; i<resultNodeList.getLength(); ++i) {
   System.out.println(resultNodeList.item(i).getTextContent());
   }

  // c) extract the coordinates of the first result
  resultNodeList = (NodeList)  

  xpath.evaluate("/GeocodeResponse/result[1]/geometry/location/*", 

  geocoderResultDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
  float lat = Float.NaN;
  float lng = Float.NaN;
  for(int i=0; i<resultNodeList.getLength(); ++i) {
  Node node = resultNodeList.item(i);
  if("lat".equals(node.getNodeName())) lat = 

  Float.parseFloat(node.getTextContent());
  if("lng".equals(node.getNodeName())) lng = 

  Float.parseFloat(node.getTextContent());
  }
  System.out.println("lat/lng=" + lat + "," + lng);

  // c) extract the coordinates of the first result
  resultNodeList = (NodeList) 

  xpath.evaluate("/GeocodeResponse/result[1]/address_component[type/text()
  = 'administrative_area_level_1']/country[short_name/text() = 'US']/*",  

  geocoderResultDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
  float lat = Float.NaN;
  float lng = Float.NaN;
  for(int i=0; i<resultNodeList.getLength(); ++i) {
  Node node = resultNodeList.item(i);
  if("lat".equals(node.getNodeName())) lat =  

  Float.parseFloat(node.getTextContent());
  if("lng".equals(node.getNodeName())) lng = 

  Float.parseFloat(node.getTextContent());
  }
  System.out.println("lat/lng=" + lat + "," + lng);

  }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the altitude for a specific point, I found this page that provide this facility, a code is provided in the page http://www.daftlogic.com/sandbox-google-maps-find-altitude.htm
I hope it will answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for contributing ...
i got the solution for converting the latitude and longitude to 3d coordinates(x,y,z)...that is
suppose that the model of earth has radius r then

```
  LAT=latitude*pi/180
  LON=longitude*pi/180
  x=r*cos(LAT)*cos(LON)
  y=r*sin(LAT)
  z=r*cos(LAT)*sin(LON)..
```